# How to copy a DataTable to a SharePoint SPList?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, splistitem

I have my source list data in the `sourceList` data table and want to copy that data to its root list.

How can I do that?

```
private void MoveToTopTaskList(DataTable sourceList, SPSite DestinationSiteCollection)
{
    SPWeb Destinationsite = DestinationSiteCollection.OpenWeb();
    SPList DestinationList = Destinationsite.Lists[TASKS];
    SPListItem DestinationListItem = DestinationList.Items.Add();

    foreach (DataRow row in sourceList.Rows)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best Approach for the above case is to Use the **ProcessBatchData** Method of the **SPWeb** Object. This will help you to update List items in to the List in Batch.

1. You need to build an XML  tags that will have details for inserting the data to the list.
2. If you have large number of records to be inserted to the list consider spliting it in to smaller batchs. Say if you have 1000 records do it in two 500 sets.
3. While building the XML make sure you use **StringBuilder** class to append the string.
4. Refer these Links [Link1][1] [Link2][2] [Link3][3] for more information on **ProcessBatchData**

In case if you want to do it using the OM. Then follow code

```
`SPWeb Destinationsite = DestinationSiteCollection.OpenWeb();
SPList DestinationList = Destinationsite.Lists[TASKS];    
SPListItem DestinationListItem = DestinationList.Items.Add();
  foreach (DataRow row in sourceList.Rows)
{
    DestinationListItem = DestinationList.Items.Add();
    DestinationListItem["Field1"]=row["Col"].ToString();
    DestinationListItem["Fieldn"]=row["Coln"].ToString();
    DestinationListItem.Update()

}
```

`
[1]:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-services/cc404818%28v=office.12%29
[2]:http://www.sharepointblogs.com/smc750/archive/2008/04/03/spweb-processbatchdata-a-list-is-a-list-is-a-list.aspx
[3]:https://web.archive.org/web/20121029142042/http://blog.dynatrace.com:80/2009/01/20/sharepoint-using-batch-updates-to-speed-up-performance/

Comment: My list is not too long, however can i make use of datatable default view somehow?

Comment: Yes you can make use of the DefaultView, You can Iterate Default View of DataTable as well using a For Each code and Do the operation as mentioned in the above code snippet.

Comment: CAn you please provide some code sample, which property make use of default view?

I might sound silly, but I am confused.

Comment: Do you want Code Samples for DataTable Default View or SP List Default View ?

Comment: If you did it, post your code for others who come across this question.